# J meter Email configuration for fail test case

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, email-validation

How I can set the email configuration for the failed test case In j meter Ex. when any test case is fail during testing cycle then email should be trigger for that specific failed case and it should notify the user

Comment: We need more detail of how the jmeter is run, on cloud, on premise, on which infra ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can check whether the previous Sampler is successful or not using [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)
2. JMeter provides [SMTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) allowing sending an arbitrary email to the specified list of recipients

So you can end up with something like:

[image]

and the "SMTP Sampler" will be executed only if "Some Sampler" fails.

See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) for working SMTP Sampler configuration example